# From connected voxels to polyhedron in linear time?

Tags: complexity-theory, computational-geometry

I have a polyhedron defined as a set of connected voxels (from a 3D array). I'd like to get a representation of this polyhedron by its polyhedral surface (since it's going to be much sparser). Can I get that in quasilinear time? Do I need my set of voxels to be represented in a particular form?

I don't even know the answer for the same question in 2D (getting the contour from a set of connected pixels) and if the results are identical.

Bonus points: If you happen to know if such a quasilinear algorithm is implemented in CGAL feel free to tell me ;)

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b4cf/ac75658a36266e0bc56bc09fd67475f1290c.pdf